# Play Framework 2.2 (scala) play.api.cache not included as standard?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2 (scala). I can not import play.api.cache._ as it is not found. I assume that it is not included as part of the standard download? How can I enable/get it.  Do I need to included it manually in SBT build profile?

Strange that an important component like caching is not included as standard.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, completely forgot. now accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. According to the [migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22):

```
Play cache is now split out into its own module. If you are using the Play cache, you will need to add this as a dependency. For example, in Build.scala:

val addDependencies = Seq(
   jdbc,
  cache,
  ...
)
```

Or if you're using build.sbt, you can add it there. `cache` seems to be included automatically in the generated build.sbt for new 2.2.x projects.

Comment: I confirm it is enabled by default for new Play projects based on Activator templates `play-*`.