# can't recognize Cache in play.api.cache._

Tags: playframework

I use Play 2.2.0, here is my code

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  "net.fwbrasil" %% "activate-play" % "1.6" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0"),
  "net.fwbrasil" %% "activate-jdbc-async" % "1.6" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0"),
  "net.fwbrasil" %% "activate-mongo-async" % "1.6" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0"),
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.180",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"
)
```

But when I type `Cache`, there is no `play.api.cache.Cache` choice for me. Even when I `import play.api.cache._` it cant recognize Cache. The same as `import play.api.cache.Cache`

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626410/play-framework-2-2-scala-play-api-cache-not-included-as-standard-do-i-need-to

Comment: thanks for response, I tried it but doesn't work

Comment: Try play clean and check again hopes this should work :)

Comment: I tried, actually I tried `sbt clean` but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about IDE auto-completion. Whenever you change your libs/dependencies, you have to update the ide project.

For Eclipse :

```
play eclipse
```

More information on [the official website.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE)

Comment: Because there is none. If you edited the `build.sbt` file, intellij is supposed to be able to reload the source etc. You can always try a invalidate cache and restart from within Intellij.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean invalidate cache?

Comment: There is an option in the IntelliJ `File` menu called `Invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: it doesn't get better

Comment: And I find there are two modules in my project, is it possible I just import cache package into a wrong module?

Comment: I removed the library of play cache from my modules and removed `cache` in my `build.sbt` then did them again, it works this time!